# Horvitz-Thompson estimator for two-stage cluster sampling

Tags: estimation, estimators, cluster-sample

So I want to apply the Horvitz-Thompson (H-T) estimator to two-stage cluster sampling.

The H-T estimator is defined as:

$$\sum\frac{Y_i}{\pi_i}$$

where $\pi_i$ is the probability of including the $i$th unit of the population in the sample.

Two-stage cluster sampling involves:

1. Randomly selecting $n$ clusters
2. Randomly selecting $m_i$ elements from cluster $i$

The probability of including $n$ clusters is $\frac{n}{N}$, where $N$ is the total number of clusters in the population.

The probability of including $m_i$ elements from cluster $i$ is $\frac{m_i}{M_i}$, where $M_i$ is the number of elements in cluster $i$.

Therefore the overall inclusion probability $\pi_i$ is $(\frac{n}{N})(\frac{m_i}{M_i})$.

So the H-T estimator I would get is:

$$\frac{N}{n}\frac{M_i}{m_i}\sum Y_i$$

However, my book says that the estimation of the population total for two-stage cluster sampling is:

$$\frac{N}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n M_i\bar Y_i$$

I'm not sure why my answer is different. My exposure to the H-T estimator is very limited, so any insight would be great.  Thank you!

Comment: The expression "$\frac{N}{n}\frac{M_i}{m_i}\sum Y_i$" is nonsensical because $i$, the index of summation, cannot appear outside the sum.

Comment: Yep, you're right! I wasn't thinking correctly about summation when I was doing this.  I reached a better answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some searching online, and I figured it out.  Given the two-stage nature of the sampling plan, the answer I came up with should actually be:

$$\frac{N}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{M_i}{m_i}\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}Y_{ij}$$

which then equals:

$$\frac{N}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n M_i \bar Y_i$$